# In fact - word choice

Tags: word-choice

Is the linking word **in fact** appropriate in this paragraph?

In my experience, it's better to have only one best friend who is always there for you in both happy and sad times (than to have lots of friends). **In fact,**  when I've experienced hardships in the past, many of my friends have turned out to be unreliable.

Comment: Why do you doubt that it might be appropriate?

Comment: 'In fact' is not a 'word'; it is a phrase of two words.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  "In fact" suggests that the following sentence adds extra information relevant to the first. It may also be used to introduce a sentence that contains information that may be contrary to the reader's expectations. In this case the reader might expect friends to be reliable, so this is contrary to the reader's expectations.

Comment: James, in this instance, does not the second sentence merely illustrate the experience recounted in the first, that it's best to rely on a single good friend rather than to look to 
several dubious ones? Would it be contrary to the reader's expectations?